# Error running Spring-Boot samples

Tags: spring-boot

I've just cloned the github repo for [Spring Boot samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot), and I am trying to run various samples but they all return the same error:

```
    c:\temp\spring-boot\spring-boot-samples\spring-boot-sample-web-jsp>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring Boot Web JSP Sample 1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.197s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 29 11:57:22 BST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/183M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
 artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:
spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Have I missed anything? Do I need to add a repo for Spring Boot? The only Spring Boot artifacts in the main maven repo are all `1.1.5.RELEASE`.  If I replace `1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` with `1.1.5.RELEASE`, it builds; but then unsurprisingly fails to run.

Comment: You need to build the dependencies first before building the sample like building the tools in your case. I would suggest you build everything once through parent's pom then you can go ahead and try building the seperate modules. In your case maven plugin "1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT" is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when I updated from `1.1.5.RELEASE`.

I ran `mvn install` from the `spring-boot` directory.

It took over 1 hour 10 minutes!

Let me know if this fixes it!

Comment: I realised this thanks to the comment to my question from ripudam.   The Spring docs could make it a lot clearer that you need to do this first before running the samples.  `mvn install` will do a `package` first BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have the pom file pointing to the snapshot repo as in this [link](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html)? The [repo link](http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/) has the maven plugin contents listed.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```